# Function doesn't want to return string slice using function arguments

Tags: string, rust, slice

I tried making a function that returns a string slice. The function takes three arguments:

1. `a` the start of the slice
2. `b` the end of slice
3. `txt` a reference to a string literal

```rust
fn main() {
    let text = String::from("My name is Ivan");

    fn get_slice(a: u8, b: u8, txt: &String) -> &str {
        &txt[a..b]
    }

    println!("{}", get_slice(4, 8, &text));
}
```

The compiler tells me:

```
error[E0277]: the type `String` cannot be indexed by `std::ops::Range<u8>`
 --> src/main.rs:5:10
  |
5 |         &txt[a..b]
  |          ^^^^^^^^^ `String` cannot be indexed by `std::ops::Range<u8>`
  |
  = help: the trait `Index<std::ops::Range<u8>>` is not implemented for `String`
```

[image: compiler response in vscodium on manjaro linux]

If I replace the range `[a..b]` with `[2..7]` or any other number range it works.

Answer (score 8):

Two things to take into consideration, slices use **`usize`** instead of `u8`. Also you would probably want to use `&str` instead of `&String`:

```rust
fn get_slice(a: usize, b: usize, txt: &str) -> &str {
    &txt[a..b]
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e260f7749a85cc303aaeedebd13083ff)